# Override default scope of a child object on cascade delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Parent
    has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end

class Child
    belongs_to :parent
    default_scope { where(deleted_at: nil).not_deleted }
end
```

My problem comes from some Child objects are soft deleted.  Calling Parent.last.destroy will attempt to destroy only those children in the default scope.

Yes, I know how to do something like `Child.last.unscoped`, but I want is for something like `Parent.find(1).destroy` to destroy all child objects, including those which have been soft deleted.

```
Parent.find(1).children.unscoped.destroy_all
Parent.destroy
```

The above works.  Is there any way to get this down to just `Parent.find(1).destroy`?

Comment: What is `A` and `bs` in `A.find(1).bs.unscoped.destroy_all` ? Are they `Parent` and `children`?

Comment: default_scope is always bad idea :( Change it to 'active' (for example) scope and use it where you need

Comment: Sorry, I was going with A and B, then edited to parent child.  I'm inheriting the code, and default scope is ingrained at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would delegate this to the database, since I doubt you need to run callbacks on records that are already soft deleted. Plus it's much faster and uses no memory.

New Migration:

```
add_foreign_key :child_table, :parent_table, on_delete: :cascade
```

Then you can simply do

```
Parent.find(1).delete
```

Comment: Good suggestion but I believe we used destroy to manage external connections and storage.